# How to match a string in a line to another string in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**column1:**

```
*packed decimal(18,2) chd_ytd_rtck_chg_am;
packed decimal(18,2) chd_ytd_deah_chg_am;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_late_ct;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_ovlm_ct;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_deah_ct;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_rtck_ct;*
```

**column 2:**

```
*chd_ytd_late_ct
chd_ytd_deah_chg_am
chd_ytd_rtck_ct*
```

If the 3rd string of the column 1 matches with the string in the column 2 then **column 3** should return **TRUE**. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if one of the items of list 2 occurs in the current item in list 1 you want to see a `True` in column 3? Tis would be a solution then, if i understood your question right.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$3,A1)))
```

[image]